# How can I make this code quicker?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a lot of 750x750 images. I want to take the geometric mean of non-overlapping 5x5 patches from each image, and then for each image, average those geometric means to create one feature per image. I wrote the code below, and it seems to work just fine. But, I know it's not very efficient. Running it on 300 or so images takes around 60 seconds. I have about 3000 images. So, while it works for my purpose, it's not efficient. How can I improve this code?

```
#each sublist of gmeans will contain a list of 22500 geometric means 
#corresponding to the non-overlapping 5x5 patches for a given image. 
gmeans = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
#the loop here populates gmeans.
for folder in range(len(subfolders)):
    just_thefilename, colorsourceimages, graycroppedfiles  = get_all_images(folder)
    for items in graycroppedfiles:
        myarray = misc.imread(items)
        area_of_big_matrix=750*750
        area_of_small_matrix= 5*5
        how_many = area_of_big_matrix / area_of_small_matrix
        n = 0 
        p = 0 
        mylist=[]
        while len(mylist) < how_many:
            mylist.append(gmean(myarray[n:n+5,p:p+5],None))
            n=n+5
            if n == 750:
                p = p+5
                n = 0
        gmeans[folder].append(my list)
#each sublist of mean_of_gmeans will contain just one feature per image, the mean of the geometric means of the 5x5 patches.
mean_of_gmeans = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
for folder in range(len(subfolders)):
    for items in range(len(gmeans[0])):
        mean_of_gmeans[folder].append((np.mean(gmeans[folder][items],dtype=np.float64)))
```

Comment: could be a good candidate for the code review partner site. Make sure you check their site rules first, though.

Comment: This indeed sounds very slow for such a simple operation (i think some code of mine calculating up to 4-th order cumulants and much much more like histogram-equalization was even faster). The first thing i would do: try [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) which gives you a function named [view_as_block](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks). This is implement by some advanced numpy function [as_strided](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#example-fake-dimensions-with-strides). I can't guarantee anything, but it could be much faster!

Comment: Code-review does not have much `numpy` traffic; while 'vectorizing' is a regular question on SO.  Also CR is pickier about format.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I will check out Code-review.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand the suggestion to move this to the code review site,
but this problem provides a nice example of the power of using vectorized
numpy and scipy functions, so I'll give an answer.

The function below, cleverly called `func`, computes the desired value.
The key is to reshape the image into a four-dimensional array.  Then
it can be interpreted as a two-dimensional array of two-dimensional
arrays, where the inner arrays are the 5x5 blocks.

[`scipy.stats.gmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gmean.html) can compute the geometric mean over more than one
dimension, so that is used to reduce the four-dimensional array to the
desired two-dimensional array of geometric means.  The return value is the
(arithmetic) mean of those geometric means.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gmean


def func(img, blocksize=5):
    # img must be a 2-d array whose dimensions are divisible by blocksize.
    if (img.shape[0] % blocksize) != 0 or (img.shape[1] % blocksize) != 0: 
        raise ValueError("blocksize does not divide the shape of img.")

    # Reshape 'img' into a 4-d array 'blocks', so blocks[i, :, j, :] is
    # the subarray with shape (blocksize, blocksize).
    blocks_nrows = img.shape[0] // blocksize
    blocks_ncols = img.shape[1] // blocksize
    blocks = img.reshape(blocks_nrows, blocksize, blocks_ncols, blocksize)

    # Compute the geometric mean over axes 1 and 3 of 'blocks'.  This results
    # in the array of geometric means with size (blocks_nrows, blocks_ncols).
    gmeans = gmean(blocks, axis=(1, 3), dtype=np.float64)

    # The return value is the average of 'gmeans'.
    avg = gmeans.mean()

    return avg
```

For example, here the function is applied to an array with shape (750, 750).

```
In [358]: np.random.seed(123)

In [359]: img = np.random.randint(1, 256, size=(750, 750)).astype(np.uint8)

In [360]: func(img)
Out[360]: 97.035648309350179
```

It isn't easy to verify that that is the correct result, so here is a much smaller example:

```
In [365]: np.random.seed(123)

In [366]: img = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=(3, 6))

In [367]: img
Out[367]: 
array([[3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3]])

In [368]: func(img, blocksize=3)
Out[368]: 2.1863131342986666
```

Here is the direct calculation:

```
In [369]: 0.5*(gmean(img[:,:3], axis=None) + gmean(img[:, 3:], axis=None))
Out[369]: 2.1863131342986666
```

Comment: Wow. I just timed my function with the 3000 images. A whooping 13 minutes! Your function - 1s. Amazing. I don't understand it totally, and I trust your skill more than I trust my skill. But, my loop and your function end up with different values after the second decimal. I wonder why that is? I tested my loop on some small 5x5 matrices, and your function on the same, and we end up with the same value. It seems that something happens with these larger matrices.

Comment: While working on this, I found that `gmean` does some casting of types that does not agree with its docstring.  If you pass `gmean` an array with type `np.uint8` (typical for an image), the result it returns has data type `np.float16`!  I avoided that by putting `img = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.float64)` as the first line of `func()`, but it turns out you can also specify the data type of the `gmean` calculation by using its `dtype` argument.  Try changing your `gmean` call to `gmean(myarray[n:n+5,p:p+5], None, dtype=np.float64)`.  I've updated my version to use this.